# Network share defined in fstab prevent user login until network is connected and the share is mounted

Tags: linux, networking, systemd, mount, automounting

After I boot my computer, the login screen comes-up quickly and I am able to login. However, the network identification is slow and the network is "connected" after a good 30 seconds / 1 minute.

I added 2 network shares (SMB) to mount on boot in `/etc/fstab` but I am not able to delay the mount until the network is connected. Thus, with the mount on boot defined, I can not login anymore until the network is "connected" (I don't get the login screen until).

Neither the option `_netdev` or `x-systemd.after=network-online.target` seems to work. In both cases, I have to wait until the network is "connected" and the shares are mounted until I can log into my session. In both case, the shares work.

Content of `fstab`:

```
//address/smb_share1  /mnt/share1  cifs  credentials=/root/.smbcredentials,uid=1000,gid=1000,x-systemd.after=network-online.target  0  0
//address/smb_share2  /mnt/share2  cifs  credentials=/root/.smbcredentials,uid=1000,gid=1000,x-systemd.after=network-online.target  0  0
```

or replacing `x-systemd.after=network-online.target` with `_netdev`.

What am I missing and what would be the correct syntax to tell my computer not to mount those 2 shares until I have a working internet connection?

Using POP_OS 22.04 LTS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use systemd [`automount`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.automount.html) to trigger a mount only when the filesystem is accessed.

```
//address/smb_share1  /mnt/share1  cifs  credentials=/root/.smbcredentials,uid=1000,gid=1000,x-systemd.automount,x-systemd.after=network-online.target  0  0
```